# How to delete key from object in React Native javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have an object named "colors" which have keys like

```
{
"white":"#FFFFFF",
"black":"#000000",
"red":"FF0000"
}
```

In some of the conditions i want all colors except the "white" color

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const source = {
"white":"#FFFFFF",
"black":"#000000",
"red":"FF0000"
};

const target = {...source};
delete target["white"]
```

Typescript Version:

```
const source = {
"white":"#FFFFFF",
"black":"#000000",
"red":"FF0000"
};

const target: Partial<typeof source> = {...source};
delete target["white"]
```

Comment: Hello @Shmyhelsyi

Thanks it is working, but I am getting one syntax error in typescript file

```
The operand of a 'delete' operator must be optional.
```

Comment: Try to define target type as Partial<typeof source>

Answer (score 1):

delete source["colourname"]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

```
let color = {
"white":"#FFFFFF",
"black":"#000000",
"red":"FF0000"
}

let filteredColor = Object.keys(color)
    .filter((key) => !key.includes("white"))
    .reduce((obj, key) => {
        return Object.assign(obj, {
          [key]: color[key]
        });
  }, {});
```

using the `filter` and `reduce` you can filter out the result

Comment: yes using this way we can do it with this, but it is not required for me , thank you

Comment: @BhavinParghi got it you can upvote if it's correct answer